# Is there a general way to write a convex piecewise-linear function?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let be $u:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a convex and piecewise-linear function.

Let $\{x_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ the sequence of point of non-derivability of $u$.

I was wondering if  there is a general form to write this function $u$.

Thanks!

Comment: If $k_ix+m_i$ meets $k_{i+1}x+m_{i+1}$ at $x=x_i$ then convexity is equivalent to $k_ix_i+m_i=k_{i+1}x_i+m_i$ and $k_{i+1}\ge k_i$. Is it what you mean?

Comment: @A.Γ. I would like to write $u$ in some way: $u(x)=...$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've seen the function $x_+=\frac{x+|x|}{2}$ used for that: a piecewise linear function $f$ can be written as $$f(x)=a_0\,x+b_0+\sum^n_{i=1}a_i\,(x-x_i)_+,$$
convexity implying $a_i\ge0$ for $i\ge1$. Is that of any use for you?